# How I make my Worksheet_change react after the 2nd entry?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to my macro to send a message just when the second cell have a value. For now the seconde I put something in the first cell my msgBox pop up!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("G557") <> Range("G555") Then

        MsgBox "It has to be equal"

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Target` in that subroutine parameter is the Range (cell) that had the change that triggered the `worksheet_change()` event. Just test that target to see if it is the cell you want to track. The most common way to do this is using the `INTERSECT()` function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G555")) Is Nothing Then
      If Range("G557") <> Range("G555") Then    
        MsgBox "It has to be equal"    
      End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Now the rest of your code will only execute if G555 was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add additional condition to your `If` statement:

```
If Range("G557") <> Range("G555") And Range("G557") <> "" And Range("G555") <> "" Then
```